# How can I convert empty strings to null in typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm sort of a newbie to typescript, i've danced around it long enough

I have two interfaces, one is reading from a database that I dont have control over and cannot trust that the values it returns are what I expect them to be.

```
// pulled from database
interface JobTableRow {
  job_number: string,
  description: string | null,
  project_manager: string | null,
  status: string | null,
  ts_customer_id: string | null,
  completed_date: string | null,
  date_stamp: string,
  time_stamp: string,
  contract_base: number,
  contract_approved_changes: number,
  contract_revised_total: number,
  jtd_cost: number,
  start_date: string | null,
  labor_tax_group: string | null,
  material_tax_group: string | null,
  subcontract_tax_group: string | null,
  equipment_tax_group: string | null,
  overhead_tax_group: string | null,
  other_tax_group: string | null,
  ts_row_id: string,
  ts_row_version: string
}
// manually calculated field after being pulled from the database
interface JobMapping extends JobTableRow {
  ts_updated: string
}
```

an example record:

```
const mapped: JobMapping = {
  job_number: '0000',
  description: 'some project',
  project_manager: 'some person',
  status: 'active',
  date_stamp: '2020-04-20',
  time_stamp: '11:12:57',
  labor_tax_group: '',
  material_tax_group: '',
  subcontract_tax_group: '',
  equipment_tax_group: '',
  overhead_tax_group: '',
  other_tax_group: '',
  // ...
  ts_updated: '2020-04-20T18:12:57.000Z'
}
```

what I am used to doing is something like this in nodejs in order to convert the empty string values to null, but typescript yells at me saying `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'JobMapping'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'JobMapping'.ts(7053)`

```
Object.keys(mapped).forEach(key => {
  if (typeof mapped[key] === 'string') {
    let val: string = mapped[key]
    if (val === '') mapped[key] = null
  }
})
```

Comment: Maybe this? https://tsplay.dev/mL542W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the error by doing this:

```js
let mapped: JobMapping = {
  job_number: '0000',
  description: 'some project',
  project_manager: 'some person',
  status: 'active',
  date_stamp: '2020-04-20',
  time_stamp: '11:12:57',
  labor_tax_group: '',
  material_tax_group: '',
  subcontract_tax_group: '',
  equipment_tax_group: '',
  overhead_tax_group: '',
  other_tax_group: '',
  // ...
  ts_updated: '2020-04-20T18:12:57.000Z'
}

Object.keys(mapped).forEach(key => {
  const keyWithType = key as keyof typeof mapped;
  let value = mapped[keyWithType];
  if (typeof value === 'string' && value === "") {
    mapped = {...mapped, [keyWithType]: null};
  }
})
```